# Remove XCode files from mac except Simulator to reduce the size

Tags: xcode, macos, ios-simulator, flutter-ios

I need to remove the Xcode from my mac to reduce the storage because it sized ~50GB now on my storage. But i need Simulator to test run my Flutter apps with iOS. Is there any way to reduce size of Xcode keeping the simulator running.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the iOS Simulator from Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes to /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes